# Project compiles but shows an "Timer-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, swing, nullpointerexception

In debbuger, the variable `fisier` from `poze = Arrays.<File>asList(fisiere);` shows as `null`, but I can't figure out why.

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

**I've pasted my files here:**

GUI http://pastebin.com/ZhHAGNxK
Phonebook class http://pastebin.com/KUk05eRd

**Console error:**

```
Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
    at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:3807)
    at java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:3794)
    at cartedetelefon.GUI.GUI.displayBanner(GUI.java:656)
    at cartedetelefon.GUI.GUI.access$000(GUI.java:27)
    at cartedetelefon.GUI.GUI$2.run(GUI.java:73)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 7 seconds)
```

**EDIT:**

The error in the SSCCE. The code below

```
package GUI;


import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;


class testClass extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    private List<File> poze;
    private Timer timer1 = new Timer();

    public testClass() {
        initComponents();


        javax.swing.Timer timer2 = new javax.swing.Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

            }
        });
        timer2.start();

        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                displayBanner();
            }
        };


        timer1.schedule(task, 1000, 4000);


    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(224, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 65, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void displayBanner(){
        URL url = getClass().getResource("/GUI"); //edited, the path was incorrect
        File dir = new File(url.getPath());

        File[] fisiere = dir.listFiles(new FileFilter() {

                @Override
                public boolean accept(File f) {
                    return f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg");
                }

            });



        poze = Arrays.<File>asList(fisiere);


        int pic = (int) (Math.random()*3);

        File f = poze.get(pic);
        ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon(f.getAbsolutePath());
        jLabel.setText("");
        jLabel.setIcon(i);
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */




    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(testClass.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(testClass.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(testClass.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(testClass.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new testClass().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: `fisiere` is `null`. Post your code here, do not link to it. If the code is long, the create a minimum working [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: That code is 766 line long. You really expect people will read it? As @BoristheSpider said, SSCCE is a good idea

Comment: i've made an SSCCE, see the edit. many thanks

Comment: Is `/img` an external directory or it's within your jar?

Comment: @dic19  the /img is another package in jar